# Input Time should be todays date pine script

Tags: pine-script, pine-script-v5

How to get a today's date in INPUT?

```
starttime = input.time(title = "starttime", defval = timestamp("30 May 2022 00:00 +0000")
```

I required defval equal to today's date.

Answer (score 1):

This cannot be done because `defval` needs to be a constant.
You'd think one could use `timenow` for that, but because this is a value that changes, it is a `series` variable instead of a `const`, and will result in a compile error.
Details can be found here: [Type system#const](https://www.tradingview.com/pine-script-docs/en/v5/language/Type_system.html#const)

A workaround could be to use `confirm=true`, so that when you add the indicator to your chart, you'll be asked to identify the start date/time location.
See this blog post for details: [Pine scripts are now interactive](https://www.tradingview.com/blog/en/pine-scripts-are-now-interactive-27147/)

```
starttime = input.time(title = "starttime", defval=0, confirm=true)
```

Comment: Thanks for reply, however I thought about confirm earlier, but dropped the idea because I do not want to add indicator every-time. Pls any other alternative method.

Comment: Unfortunately, there's no alternative way afaik.